# ios difficult fetchRequest FetchedResultController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I cann't create fetchRequest for fetchedResultedController.

I have 3 models:

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Entertainment *entertainment;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Place *place;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * objectId;
    //boolValue
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * threeDimensional;
    //others properties
    .......
@end


@interface Entertainment : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * objectId;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *events;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *classNaming;
    //others properties
    .......
@end


@interface Place : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * objectId;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *events;
    //others properties
    .......
@end
```

So I need to show places in `tableView` (1 place for each row) for concrete day (example 1 November) and concrete `entertainment` with all events time (example event may have time 14:30, and second 19:10, so I need show all this times in cell for concrete place)

Example:

[image]

So it's not difficult

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForEntertainmentsWithEventsFromEntertainment:(Entertainment *)entertainment 
date:(NSDate *)date
{
    if (!place && !date)
        return nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Event class])];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy/MM/dd";
    NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
    NSDateComponents *oneDay = [NSDateComponents new];
    oneDay.day = 1;
    NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:startDate options:0];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date < %@ AND entertainment.classNaming == %@ AND entertainment.objectId == %@", startDate, endDate, entertainment.classNaming, entertainment.objectId];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"entertainment.name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"place.name" cacheName:nil];
    return fetchResultsController;
}
```

So I get fetchedResultsController, where every section is Place with array of rows, each of it is Event for this Place.

But I have big problem:
Every `Event` can shown in 3D (property `threeDimensional`). SO if Place have like 3D and non-3D events it must be divided, so one cell will be show 3D events for place and another non-3D events for place. I did it but without fetchedResultsCOntroller. And what predicate I need use in fetchRequest to make like this:

[image]

Comment: No can do without some changes to your model. I don't think you can't expect a fetch request for Events to return the same Event multiple times in the results set.

Comment: Why don't you move the threeDimensional property from Event to the Place entity? That should make the task easier. Note also that the first sort descriptor must correspond to the sectionNameKeyPath.